# Converting a number like "1 1/2" to decimal

Tags: t-sql

I have a function I created to remove characters and keep the number, but I have a problem with x/y values such as 1 1/2 where this would be 1.5.  Currently I have this where it will do the percent part, but it will not include the first number... ie..  .5 instead of 1.5.  How can I do this?   Here is what I have...

```
CASE 
When (@input + ' ') like '%/%' and @input not like '%+%'
    Then cast(cast(SUBSTRING ((@input + ' '), CHARINDEX('/',(@input + ' '))-1,1) as decimal (4,2)) 
            / cast(SUBSTRING ((@input + ' '), CHARINDEX('/',(@input + ' '))+1,1) as decimal (4,2)) as float)
When @input not like '%+%'
    Then @input   
END
```

Comment: If you absolutely must do this in SQL Server then you'll need to expand your string parsing logic to cover these circumstances where you have a space between the whole number and the fraction.  Otherwise, don't make SQL Server do this.... Use a different tool.

Comment: Example values and expected output would be nice.

Comment: Here is the value that I have that I need to convert: 36 3/7 which should be 36.4286 rounded to 4 decimal places.  This should never be entered this way, but it is a varchar field so it can be entered this way.

Comment: @squillman, unfortunately this is how we are doing this process and I need to code around mistakes that people are entering these values.

Comment: I figured this out, it is ugly but it works.  The first two characters will always be a 2 digit number.  The values entered should always be 2 digits, but 2 digits with decimal are allowed.  Somewhere down the line someone thought entering "3/7" would be a good thing.  This is not a suggested way of entering the value, but it's is being done.  Thanks for the suggesting, it made me think harder.  :)

Comment: CASE 
When ('36 3/7' + ' ') like '%/%' and '36 3/7' not like '%+%'
    Then cast(left('35,.23', CHARINDEX(',',REVERSE('35,.23'))-2) 
            + cast(SUBSTRING (('36 3/7' + ' '), CHARINDEX('/',('36 3/7' + ' '))-1,1) as decimal (4,2)) 
            / cast(SUBSTRING (('36 3/7' + ' '), CHARINDEX('/',('36 3/7' + ' '))+1,1) as decimal (4,2)) as float)
When '36 3/7' not like '%+%'
    Then '36 3/7'   
END

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another trick is to abuse dynamic sql to eval the equation.

**Example:**

> ```
> DECLARE @input VARCHAR(10) = '1 1/2';
> DECLARE @result DECIMAL(5,2);
>
> DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(100) = 'select @res=('+replace(@input,' ', '+1.0*')+')';
> DECLARE @params NVARCHAR(100) = N'@res DECIMAL(5,2) OUTPUT';
>
> EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @sql, @params, @result OUTPUT;
> SELECT @result AS result;
> ```

| result |
| --- |
| 1.50 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=aa45baaf6791aa31c01d27bfecbb2845)*